# setInterval not working in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have some javascript code that doesnt seem to be automatically updating on the page, any ideas? Have i setInterval correctly?

```
function updatePrice(id, currentPrice){

    var newPrice = 0;
    currentPrice = currentPrice * 100
    if(rate == 1){
        newPrice = currentPrice - 1;

    }
    if(rate == 2){

        newPrice = currentPrice - 2;
    }
    if(rate == 3){

        newPrice = currentPrice - 3;
    }
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = newPrice;
}

updatePrice('reverse', currentPrice);
var timeinterval = setInterval(updatePrice, 60000);
```

EDIT
Thanks for everyones help, the only problem i have with passing arguments via updatePrice is that i want the price to decrease every minute, how would i set the argument to include the new price that has been calculated in the updatePrice function?

For example i think i would need something like:
setInterval( function() { updatePrice('reserve',newPrice); }, 60000);

The newPrice being the price just calculated in updatePrice.

Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: Your interval is calling `updatePrice` but not passing any arguments...

Comment: In your setInterval, you are calling updatePrice with no arguments.

Comment: The error console may provide illumination.  `currentPrice` seems to be a global and an argument name, the latter shadows the former.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Answer (score 3):

Try this `setInterval( function() { updatePrice(10,3); }, 60000);`

Answer (score 0):

```
function updatePrice(id, currentPrice){
    var newPrice = 0;
    currentPrice = currentPrice * 100
    if(0 < rate && rate < 4) {           // shorten this (it's clearer)
        newPrice = currentPrice - rate;
    }
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = newPrice;
}

updatePrice('reverse', currentPrice); // calling updatePrice with parameters (OK)
var timeinterval = setInterval(function() [
    updatePrice(/* SOME PARAMETERS ARE NEEDED HERE */); // should pass in some params
}, 60000);
```